# Job sites for finding postdoc and other academic positions in Germany or other EU countries (aside from Euraxess or academic positions)

Tags: job-search, job, germany, spain

I'm trying to find job sites specific to European countries like Germany, Spain etc. I'm aware that some of these jobs are posted on Euraxess or academic positions, or even regular job sites like LinekdIn, Indeed or Glassdoor, although I'd not characterize the last three as good resources for finding academic jobs. For France, I'm aware of the following sites:

GDR Kiosque: http://www.gdr-isis.fr/kiosque.html, https://gdr-mia.math.cnrs.fr/(2) ML Google groups: (1) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/ml-news/academic-position, (2) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/ml-news/postdoctoral-position 
(3) https://scholarshipdb.net/ ,      https://academicpositions.com/  c) Operations postes:
[http://postes.smai.emath.fr/current/index.php](http://postes.smai.emath.fr/current/index.php%C2%A0%C2%A0)  
d) Jobs in epidemiology, pathogen ecology etc.
[https://iddjobs.org/](https://iddjobs.org/%C2%A0%C2%A0)  
e) CNRS postdocs: https://emploi.cnrs.fr/, https://carrieres.cnrs.fr/en/employment-opportunities https://emploi.cnrs.fr/Offres/CDD/UMR5525-ELSGEN-011/Default.aspxhttps://emploi.cnrs.fr/RechercheAvancee.aspx

You'll notice that most of these sites apply to France only, not other countries. Now I'm looking for postdocs and tenure tracks in different EU coutries, but I'm unsure what are some good sites where I can find these opportunities - it seems they're published on the individual lab/university sites.

P.S. My area of research is geometric statistics, applied math, mathematical image analysis etc if that's relevant.

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!